# this is undefined inside prototype function

Tags: javascript

I have below two functions in two seperate files:

```
//homeFunction.js

import secondaryFunc from "./secondaryFunction.js";

const secFunc = new secondaryFunc(3);

secFunc.sayHello(5);
```

The another file is secondaryFunction.js:

```
function secondaryFunc(val){
    this.val = val;
}

secondaryFunc.prototype.sayHello = (val1)=>{
    console.log(this);
    console.log("Hello");
}

export default secondaryFunc;
```

Here, when I execute `homeFunction`, `this` is undefined inside `sayHello` function, which I don't understand because I have already created a reference to the `secondaryFunc`, which has `sayHello` as a property, so `this` should not be undefined inside `sayHello`. Please help me to understand this anomaly.

Thanks!